# Node to convert tf messages to tf2

Tags: ros, laser-scan-matcher, tf2, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I know tf is depreciated, and that it has been transfered to tf2. I was wondering if anyone has an idea how to convert tf messages to tf2. Particularly, I am using laser scan matcher that is supposed to be supported only till indigo. The laser scan matcher is based off tf, so it possible to transfer tf to tf2? I am new to this, not sure how to do it.

I have looked at the tutorials for tf2, but I am not sure how to build a node for this. Any suggestions, or guidance is appreciated.  Here are the links I have looked through:
Laser Scan Matcher Link: http://wiki.ros.org/laser_scan_matcher
TF2 Conversion: http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials

Software: Ubuntu 16.04, Kinetic

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/261003/node-to-convert-tf-messages-to-tf2/) by [hdbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30050/hdbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 36 on 2017-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The present `tf` implementation uses `tf2` for its underlying message and data handling.

So, I think the job has already been done.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2017-05-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hdbot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30050/hdbot/) on 2017-05-04**:
Ahh ok, thanks, I wasn't sure if this transfer had been made.